# Can't get Cloudinary video payer to work with Require.js

Tags: requirejs, video-streaming, magento2, cloudinary

I'm working on Magento 2 sites which loads all of its JavaScript with Require.js.

On one of the pages, I need to be able to let the user upload images & videos and also play the video back to them.

I've easily been able to add the Cloudinary upload widget and have it working with Require.js by following [their instructions](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#quick_example).

However, I can't get their video player to work after following [their video player instructions](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudinary_video_player#introduction_and_setup).

I get the following errors in the browser console:

> GET
>   https://5d5338dbc1c44f0f87cf4daaf823446c.production.codepen.plumbing/js/cloudinary-core.js
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>
> index.html?d=1538061283375:17 Uncaught Error: Script error for
>   "cloudinary-core", needed by:
>   //unpkg.com/cloudinary-video-player/dist/cld-video-player.min.js
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>       at makeError (require.js:165)
>       at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1732)

Any idea how can I fix this?

I've reproduced the error on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/holly845/project/editor/DQNQmd#

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My New Pen!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" id="upload_widget_opener">Upload multiple images</a>
  <br />
<div style="max-width: px">
<video id="doc-player"  controls  muted  class="cld-video-player cld-fluid"></video>
</div>

  <script data-main="/js/config" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.22/require.js"></script>
  <script>
    require(['config'], function() {
      require(['custom'])
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**js/config.js**

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js',
  paths: {
    jquery: [
      'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4',
      'lib/jquery.min'
    ]
  }
});
```

**js/custom.js**

```
define([
  'jquery',
  '//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js',
  '//unpkg.com/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap.min.js',
  '//unpkg.com/cloudinary-video-player/dist/cld-video-player.min.js'
], function($){
    $( "#upload_widget_opener" ).click(function() {
      cloudinary.openUploadWidget(
        { cloud_name: 'demo', upload_preset: 'a5vxnzbp'}, 
        function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });
    });   

  var cld = cloudinary.Cloudinary.new({ cloud_name: 'demo' });
var demoplayer = cld.videoPlayer('doc-player', {
  fontFace: 'Yatra One',
  playlistWidget: {
    direction: 'vertical',
    total:5
    }}).width(600);


demoplayer.playlistByTag('video_race', { 
  sourceParams: { overlay: "cloudinary_icon", opacity: 80, effect:  "brightness:200", width: 100, gravity: "north_east", x: 20, y: 10 },  autoAdvance: 0, repeat: true, presentUpcoming: 5 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you call `cloudinary-core` from src="js/cloudinary-core.js" without adding it to the js folder.
However, If you already add the //unpkg.com/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core-shrinkwrap.min.js you don't need to add the cloudinary-core.js.

Can you please remove it and let me know if that helps?